# Java contains a string or not?

Tags: java, string, boolean

http://codingbat.com/prob/p126880

Given two strings, return true if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive"). Note: str.toLowerCase() returns the lowercase version of a string.

I cannot get when it is true, it always gives false.

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) 
{
  //variables

  a.toLowerCase();
  b.toLowerCase();
  String f1="";
  String f2="";
  int d=0;
  int sum=0;

  //Program code;
  if(a.length()-b.length()>0)
  {
     (f1).equals(a);
     (f2).equals(b);
     d=a.length();
  }
  else if(a.length()-b.length()<0)
  {
     (f1).equals(b);
     (f2).equals(a); //gett**ing bigger and lower String**
     d=b.length();
  }
  else if((a).equals(b))
     sum++;

  // I think problem is because it is not enter the for.
  for(int i=0; i>d; i++)
  {
     if((f1.substring(i,i+f2.length())).equals(f2))
     sum++;  
  }

  if(sum>0)
     return true;
  else
     return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `(f1).equals(a)` to do?

Comment: I want to make f1 to equal a

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: If you want to make f1 to equal a, you should write `f1=a;`

Comment: `a.toLowerCase();` <-- won't work. `String` is final! You have to affect the value of this to a variable

Comment: Firstly i made it f1=a, it gave the same result as (f1).equals(a)

Comment: If you make use of `String` class methods, this question has a one line answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of what you are trying to achieve to test in your Java IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse whatever. This is really simple, the String object has an endsWith method so why try to invent something yourself.

If you have any troubles reading this code hit me up, should be quite straight forward. You will just have to convert your string to lowercase, that's for you to add.

```
public class StringEnds {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("String a: ");
    String a = scanner.next();
    System.out.printf("String b: ");
    String b = scanner.next();

    // Compare a and b
    if (endsWith(a, b)) {
        System.out.printf("Succes\n");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Fail\n");
    }
}

public static boolean endsWith(String firstString, String secondString) {
    return firstString.endsWith(secondString) || secondString.endsWith(firstString);
}
```

}

Here's your codebat solution (it is quite short):

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
return a.toLowerCase().endsWith(b.toLowerCase()) || b.toLowerCase().endsWith(a.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. I tried both ways, hope it helps.

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {

    int small = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());

    if (a.length()==b.length() && a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (small==a.length()) {
        if (b.substring(b.length()-small).equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
            return true;
        }

        // from here is the toLowerCase() method.
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();

    } else if (small==b.length()) {
        if (a.endsWith(b)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```